# Why don't I see an event hub when I create an IoT Hub?

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

My understanding is that Azure IoT Hub is built on top of Azure Event Hub technology, and, when an IoT hub is created, an event hub is created, under the hood. I've created an IoT hub and wrote some C# code to send messages to it, and read messages from it (using the C# EventHubClient library).

In the Portal, when I look at all the event hubs created, I don't see any (of course, I do see the IoT hub I created, as a different object). If IoT hub does indeed create an event hub why wouldn't I see the underlying event hub that IoT hub would have created?

Comment: You have an access to the internal Event Hub only for consuming messages/events, see the IoT Hub/Endpoints/Events properties such as Retention time and Consumer groups. This is an Event Hub compatible endpoint with a Listen policy, only.

Comment: @RomanKiss - If you want to write this up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an access to the internal *Event Hub* only for consuming messages/events, see the IoT Hub/Endpoints/Events properties such as Retention time and Consumer groups. This is an Event Hub compatible endpoint with a Listen policy, only.

The following screen snippet shows an Event Hub compatible endpoint of the Azure IoT Hub:

[image]